# Torque at a disc sandwiched between two rotating discs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

[image]I have a question in my mind regarding torque transfer taking place in the current situation. There are three rotation elements *A*, *B* & *C* as shown in the figure.

- The rotating element *A* is connected to an input shaft which transfer torque $T_a$ and at an angular speed omega $\omega$
- The rotating element *B* is connected to the element *A* by rigid bar to make it rotate together
- The rotating element *C* makes contact with *A* and *B* at a thin strip on the edge of the circumference lined by friction material

My question is if $T_a$ is the torque transferred to element *A*, then what will be the torque output $T_c$ at shaft for rotating element *C*?

My source of confusion was that the force at interface *AC* and *BC* would $F = T_a/r$ on both sides. This equals a total force of $2*T_a/r$ on *C*. But then $P_{in} = T_a * \omega$ is not equal to $P_{out}$ at $C = 2 * T_a * \omega$ . This can't be true! So where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hi Masoom and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please keep in mind that there will be people reading your question who don't know what a clutch, transmission, flywheel, or pressure plate is. Could you please edit your question to explain what these things are and how they're connected? Or if you can rephrase the question to talk about a system of gears and levers and such, that would be even better.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with a description of clutch assembly and provided a link to an animated version at the bottom of the question

Comment: What you are missing is the load torque on _B_. That is the load due to the acceleration and drag of a car. Without this resistance the clutch would accelerate rotationally wildly.

Comment: Due to friction $P_{in} \neq P_{out}$.

Comment: @ja72 Only the disc 'C' i.e, the clutch disc is connected to the output shaft. Right now assume no drive is being transferred to the wheels and let's just focus on the torque transmitted to shaft 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine pushing open a door with a force of $10 N$.  Now you change from using your palm to using your 5 fingers.  Each finger doesn't apply $10 N$ of force, instead the sum of the forces together is $10 N$.  If one finger pushes harder, the force on the others will decrease.

In your case, the engine is able to deliver a total torque of $T$ to the input side of the clutch.  What the distribution of that torque is inside you cannot say, only the total.  You might want to assume that each side of the plate gets $\frac{T}{2}$ torque, but dividing it up is probably not useful.

Comment: Hi @BowlOfRed - I have reformatted the question. I understand your point for the case of a door. But I don't know how we can apply the same hypothesis over here? As we can see that 'A' and 'B' are rotating together, so they will have same torque. When we think about the interface with 'C', both should have same force T_a / r at the top! I don't know how there will be unequal division

Comment: Rotating together doesn't mean they have the same torque, just like the fingers moving together don't have the same force.

Comment: Ok. let's remove the center plate and have two discs bolted together such as A and B. Let there be one bolt each at top and bottom (diametrically opposite). Won't they have same amount of Torque? They should have, as the input disc, asuume 'A' will push the other disc through the bolt by a force T/r at top and bottom, forming a couple [T/r * r] = T

Comment: Where does B get its torque to transfer?  It gets it from A. So if you want to consider A and B separately, you have to account for the torque transfer between them.  $T_A = T_{A->B}  + T_{A->C}$

Answer (score 0):

When disk is slipping $\omega_c < \omega_a$ and $ T_c = \mu 2 N R$ where $N$ is the contact force.

If the disk sticks then $T_c=T_a$ and $\omega_c=\omega_a$

The transition occurs when $N=\frac{T_c}{2 \mu R}$ and $P_{out} \leq P_{in}$ always.

Comment: That was helpful thanks. So the advantage of having two friction faces is that twice the torque can be transmitted

Comment: Yes, twice the torque for the same contact force $N$.